# Will be + "-ing" continuous verb form

Tags: future-continuous

What is the meaning of *will be + <strike>infinitive</strike> "-ing" continuous verb form?*

For example: *I will be buying it.*

When do we use this structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use will be + -ing form (present participle, not bare infinitive) to form the future continuous to talk about future actions. It's used to express that something will be in progress at or around a time in the future.

I'll be out at 6 o'clock tomorrow. I'll be buying a car. It means that I  will be in the middle of buying a car at/around this time tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

> I will be buying it.

The only infinitive here is *be*, which is required by the modal auxiliary *will*; *buying* is a present participle. This is a future version of the progressive:

> PRESENT PROGRESSIVE: I **am** buying a hamburger right now.
>   PAST PROGRESSIVE: I **was** buying a hot dog yesterday when I met Kevin.
>   FUTURE PROGRESSIVE: I **will be** buying a BLT for lunch tomorrow.

Comment: You're answer is good but it doesn't contain "Simple" English. I think it doesn't explain the difference in meaning as well.